# How to view the metrics ready to be sent off to Datadog

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

So I am new to metrics and micrometer. I am have followed this [tutorial](https://mokkapps.de/blog/monitoring-spring-boot-application-with-micrometer-prometheus-and-grafana-using-custom-metrics/) in which we set up some basics Meters like a counter and a Gauge and expose the metrics. I am able to see the metrics when I hit the endpoint `/actuator/prometheus`. I can seem my custom meters there.

So now I am trying to expose the metrics to datadog. I have imported the following dependency:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-datadog</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

and also have this on my application.properties file:

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`

`management.metrics.export.datadog.apiKey=123`

I am aware i have not included any url to data or any of that sort but i was under the impression that i could simply see the metrics im collecting via the actuator endpoint by accessing something like `/actuator/datadog`? Is my understanding correct? I essentially want to see the metrics im collecting before sending it out to datadog. Is this possible?

Comment: Datadog doesn't include an actuator endpoint since it is a push model. The '/actuator/metrics' endpoint will be a good option though. Also you could enable the LoggingMeterRegistry to see what is being pushed via your logs

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't see any metrics under `/actuator/datadog` since the metrics are pushed rather than pulled.

The usual approach used in a Spring Boot application together with Datadog is to send data out from the app is over *UDP* and utilizing the StatsD protocol for the message structure. You can achieve this by adding `micrometer-registry-statsd` to your dependency which will auto-configure the app.

Some config for Datadog:

```
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      statsd:
        enabled: true
        flavor: datadog
      defaults:
        enabled: true
      datadog:
        api-key: 123456
```

**How can you inspect the metrics before it is sent to datadog?**

One way of doing this during development is to  inspect the UDP messages, so basically spin up a UDP server on `localhost` and port `8125` (these are the default values but can be overridden).

I was in the same situation some time ago and wrote my own UDP server, you can see it here https://github.com/hcgoranson/UDP-server

Comment: I also faced this issue and UDP server proved to be helpful. Issue in my case was classpath still did not had the micrometer-registry-statsd jars even after adding to pom.xml . I had to refresh maven dependencies. Thanks for the approach.